# Whats wrong with this linkedlist implementation?

Tags: c, linked-list

After breaking my head over this for quite sometime, I am looking for help.  Maybe I am doing something really silly here.  Below is a basic implementation of linkedlist.  However, it does not seem to work.  Can someone please take a look?

EDIT: By not working I mean its getting in to an endless loop in the else part of the add function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* link;
};

void add(struct node** list, int i)
{
    //populate a node
    node* tempNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    tempNode->data = i; //**This does not seem to initialize data**
    tempNode->link = NULL; //**Same here**

    //check if the list is empty
    if(*list == NULL)
    {
        //create the node
        *list = tempNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while((*list)->link != NULL); //Enters in to an endless loop here because the link is not initialized
        (*list)->link = tempNode;
    }

}

void print(node** list)
{
    node* itr = *list;
    while(itr != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << itr->data << "\n";
        itr = itr->link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node* linkedList = NULL;
    node** t = &linkedList;
    add(&linkedList, 10);
    add(&linkedList, 20);
    add(&linkedList, 30);
    add(&linkedList, 40);
    print(&linkedList);

}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive on what you mean by "not work". We can't read minds :)

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Added it to the edits

Comment: On a general note, you should check if `malloc` returns `NULL` to prevent segmentation faults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add` function is wrong (the `else` branch). Since `(*list)->link` doesn't get changed, **it will loop forever**. Try this.

```
void add(struct node** list, int i)
{
    /* .... */
    if(*list == NULL)
        *list = tempNode;
    else {
        struct node *p = *list;
        /* Search for tail. */
        while(p->link)
            p = p->link;

        /* Since p->link is NULL, it's the tail. */
        p->link = tempNode;
    }
}
```

This inserts in `O(n)`; user786653 has a nice suggestion in the comments.

Comment: +1 Beaten to the punch. Also since this walks the list every time people usually insert at the start of the list or keep a tail pointer to avoid the walking.

Comment: @user786653 I like to keep a `struct` with a "head" and a "tail" :-)

Comment: Also, we don't need the `if..else` anymore.

Comment: @keks But the first time `*list` will be `NULL`, no?

Comment: DOH!!  Wonder why I did not see that.

Comment: @cnicutar - Why not keep a `len` in your head/tail `struct` as well? Save some time.

Answer (score 1):

> while((*list)->link != NULL); //Enters in to an endless loop here because the link is not initialized

Well, you shouldn't be trying to use an uninitialized value anyway; make sure it gets initialized first.

But obviously the problem occurs with any non-null value: there's no way inside the loop for the value to change, so it will continue to be non-null forever. Maybe you should re-think the logic? What is this part of the code supposed to do, and why?

(I am deliberately not answering directly so you can do your own thinking - it's an important skill.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `add()`:

```
    else
    {
        struct node *n = *list;
        while (n->link != NULL)
            n = n->link;
        n->link = tempNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version. I'm not sure, but it might be the case that reading this one and comparing it to yours will  teach you more than reading an analysis of the difference.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
  int data;
  node* link;
};

void add(struct node** list, int i)
{
  // populate a node
  node* tempNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  tempNode->data = i;
  tempNode->link = NULL;

  //check if the list is empty
  if(*list == NULL)
    *list = tempNode; //create the node
  else {
    while((*list)->link != NULL)
      list = &(*list)->link;
    (*list)->link = tempNode;
  }
}

void print(node** list)
{
  node* itr = *list;
  while(itr != NULL) {
    std::cout << itr->data << "\n";
    itr = itr->link;
  }
}

int main()
{
  node* linkedList = NULL;
  add(&linkedList, 10);
  add(&linkedList, 20);
  add(&linkedList, 30);
  add(&linkedList, 40);
  print(&linkedList);
}
```